# PHP | SQL - Проблема сохранения данных по своим местам

Tags: php, sql, запись

Здравствуйте, дорогие друзья!

Проблема у меня заключается в том, что есть массив данных в таблице.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть input **(id)** изображения в базе данных и input **(index)** номер сортировки (сортировка - это вывод фотографии согласно индексу от 1-50).

Проблема в том, что нужно после нажатия кнопки **"Сохранить"**, чтобы данные по индексу сохранились по конкретных **id** к которым они привязаны. Второй день сижу, никак понять этого не могу.

Пытался, что-то

```
    if (isset($_POST['sort_project_save'])) {

    $__index = defender_hack($_POST['index_img']);
    $__id = defender_hack($_POST['id_img']);

    R::exec('UPDATE `file_multi` SET `index` = "'.$__index.'" WHERE id = "'.$__id.'"');

    foreach($__index as $key) {

        // 
    }
    echo "<script>confirm('Сохранить изменения?');</script>";
}
```

Вывод этих же фотографий в таблице осуществлен таким образом

```
                                <?php foreach ($table_file as $d) : ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" readonly name="id_img[]" value="<?=$d['id']?>"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="<?=$d['filename']?>" alt="<?=$d['name_photo']?>">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="index_img[]" value="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="?delete_photo=<?=$d['id']?>" class="delete"></a>
                                        <a href="<?=$d['filename']?>" target="_blank" class="view"></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: вот честное слово, замучаетесь с этими численными индексами. Сделайте перетаскиваемые мышью строки, благо с помощью jquery ui это делается в несколько строк

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать и буду искренне благодарен Вам за это!

Comment: Я буду очень благодарен за два примера, то что мне нужно конкретно и Ваш пример с jQuery UI.

Comment: попробуйте имена полей сделать в виде `index_img[$d['id']]` по идее должен получится на входе в POST массив с элементами с ключами id

Comment: Вышла такая строка
<input type="text" name="index_img[580]" value="">

Comment: Можете помочь с этим мне в скайпе?

Comment: Что никто не может помочь с банальной проблемой?